# Java Swing GUI with text and picture pane

Tags: java, swing

I have created a GUI in java where in the upper part text messages should be displayed and in the lower part a picture. The size of the GUI should be as I have specified it. The problem is that the picture takes the whole space and scrolling is introduced. I would like to split the space half between the text and the picture (independent if there is text or not). Moreover the picture should be scaled down so that there are no scroll bars.

Last but not least, I would like to remove pictures and add pictures on the fly. If I remove the picture the text messages should take the whole space.

How can this be done? My code is the following:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame(title);
StyleContext sc = new StyleContext();
final DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument(sc);

tPaneApp = new JTextPane(doc);
f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(tPaneApp));
f.setLocation(800, 0);

 // Add picture
try {
    String path = "C:/Users/me/Desktop/2331.jpg";
    File file = new File(path);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(label);
    f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

f.setSize(800, 800);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Should the GUI be resizable?

Comment: Learn about and use the layout managers. A GridLayout can split a container such as a JPanel, then put the JScrollPane after the text-containing components.

Comment: [The layout tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: @Ansharja If possible it should be resizable.

Comment: I don't know if you would like to have a JSplitPane, which is the best component to split your GUI in multiple two parts, however you could also use a GridLayout, as @HovercraftFullOfEels stated above. To size your image based on the panel size you can use drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height, ImageObserver observer), where width and height parameters will be panel's width and height.

Comment: @machinery If you need more help filling the panel with the image, or letting the text messages to take the whole space if no image is selected, please ask a new question.